# Asterisk and websocket: "rejecting secure audio stream without encription details"

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying this library using the test service: http://tryit.jssip.net/

When I register, using WS, not WSS, peer is registered succesfully

When I make a call i got

"rejecting secure audio stream without encription details"

Do you know a possible reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting the impossible. You cannot both have secure symmetric encryption and send keys in the clear. If you want to send the keys in the clear, you cannot use SRTP. If you want to use SRTP, you need a secure channel to send the keys on.

Comment: ... I'm sending what ??! 

I've not control over the client I linked in the above post. So please, tell me how to modify asterisks to work with in this situation, because I cannot change client ...

Comment: Either use WSS or don't use SRTP. But WS and SRTP can't work together. It's impossible.

Comment: ok ... how can I avoid to use srtp ? Must  I modify what in asterisk ?

Comment: Just remove the [security requirements](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Specifics), then the connections will work without security.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I used these -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/7695345/  settings for my users. I am also getting the same error. Can you please suggest me what I need to change so that call can be made successfull. I am calling from 1113 (web browser chrome) to 1114 (Xlite).